# Problem with saving spark DataFrame as Hive table

Tags: python, apache-spark, hive, pyspark

I have two spark's data frames. One of them recieved from hive table using HiveContext:

```
spark_df1 = hc.sql("select * from testdb.titanic_pure_data_test")
```

Second spark's dataframe I got from `.csv` file:

```
lines = sc.textFile("hdfs://HDFS-1/home/testdb/1500000_Sales_Records.csv").map(lambda line: line.split(","))    

spark_df_test = lines.toDF(['Region','Country','Item_Type','Sales_Channel','Order_Priority','Order_Date','Order_ID','Ship_Date','Units_Sold','Unit_Price','Unit_Cost','Total_Revenue','Total_Cost','Total_Profit'])`
```

I want to save any dataframe as hive table

`spark_df1.write.mode("overwrite").format("orc").saveAsTable("testdb.new_res5")`

The first dataframe saved without problems, but when I try to save second dataframe (`spark_df_test`) in the same way, I got this error

> File "/home/jup-user/testdb/scripts/caching.py", line 90, in 
>       spark_df_test.write.mode("overwrite").format("orc").saveAsTable("`testdb`.`new_res5`")
>     File "/data_disk/opt/cloudera/parcels/CDH-5.15.1-1.cdh5.15.1.p0.4/lib/spark/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/sql/readwriter.py", line 435, in saveAsTable
>     File "/data_disk/opt/cloudera/parcels/CDH-5.15.1-1.cdh5.15.1.p0.4/lib/spark/python/lib/py4j-0.10.7-src.zip/py4j/java_gateway.py", line 1257, in **call**
>     File "/data_disk/opt/cloudera/parcels/CDH-5.15.1-1.cdh5.15.1.p0.4/lib/spark/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/sql/utils.py", line 51, in deco
>   pyspark.sql.utils.AnalysisException: 'Specifying database name or other qualifiers are not allowed for temporary tables. If the table name has dots (.) in it, please quote the table name with backticks (`).;'

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The problem is you are trying to overwrite the same hive table with the different dataframe. This can't be done right now in spark.

The reason is the following [code](https://apache.googlesource.com/spark/+/branch-1.6/sql/catalyst/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/sql/catalyst/analysis/Catalog.scala#66). This ensures if the table exists to throw an exception. The ideal way is to save the dataframe in a new table

`spark_df_test.write.mode("overwrite").format("orc").saveAsTable("testdb.new_res6")`

Or you can use 'insertInto'

`spark_df_test.write.mode("overwrite").saveAsTable("temp_table")`

Then you can overwrite rows in your target table

```
val tempTable = sqlContext.table("temp_table") 
tempTable
       .write
       .mode("overwrite").insertInto("testdb.new_res5")
```

Comment: Welcome, @VladimirSazonov! One request Could you please accept my answer

Comment: The link is broken